# Abort\Retry\Ignore в любой точке кода для возможности вывалить выбор на пользователя

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

При операциях с сетью и IO часто вылазят ограничения, которые легко решить даже пользователю (пусть и опытному, да), но сложно узнать о них заранее. Занятый файл, нестабильное соединение - мне часто нехватает кнопки повторить, особенно когда весь процесс берет и откатывается.

Накидал пока на коленке реализацию более-менее универсального решения этой проблемы:

```
  public enum ExceptionHandle
  {
    Abort,
    Retry,
    Ignore
  }

  public class ExceptionEventArgs
  {
    public Exception Exception { get; }

    public ExceptionHandle? Handled { get; set; }

    public ExceptionEventArgs(Exception ex)
    {
      this.Exception = ex;
    }
  }

  public static class ExceptionHandler
  {
    public static event EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs> Handler;

    public static void TryExecute(Action action)
    {
      TryExecute(() => { action(); return true; }, false);
    }

    public static T TryExecute<T>(Func<T> action, T whenIgnored)
    {
      ExceptionHandle? handled = ExceptionHandle.Retry;
      while (handled == ExceptionHandle.Retry)
      {
        try
        {
          return action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          handled = OnHandler(new ExceptionEventArgs(ex));
          if (handled.HasValue)
          {
            switch (handled.Value)
            {
              case ExceptionHandle.Abort:
                throw;
                break;
              case ExceptionHandle.Retry:
                break;
              case ExceptionHandle.Ignore:
                break;
              default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
          }
          else
          {
            throw;
          }
        }
      }
      return whenIgnored;
    }

    private static ExceptionHandle? OnHandler(ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
      if (Handler == null || !Handler.GetInvocationList().Any())
      {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e.Exception).Throw();
      }
      else
      {
        Handler.Invoke(null, e);
      }
      return e.Handled;
    }
  }
```

Таким образом, любой подписчик `ExceptionHandler.Handler` может либо резолвить проблемы в автоматическом режиме, либо вываливать решение на пользователя.
Любой опасный код теперь можно обернуть:

```
      var tested = ExceptionHandler.TryExecute(() =>
      {
        using (var destination = new MemoryStream())
        {
          using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
            stream.CopyTo(destination);
          return destination.Length == entry.Length;
        }
      }, false);
```

В целом, текущая реализация мне кажется уже терпимой и она работает. Но, подозреваю, что такие решения уже где то есть, просто я не смог их найти. Может кто-то посоветует где взять или хотя бы посмотреть готовые решения? Ну и, если в моем коде есть косяки - тоже не отказался бы от помощи.

UPD: да, я понимаю, что даже так остаются проблемные ситуации - экшн может быть одноразовым (закрывать соединение, гробить sql сессию, да что угодно делать). Это уже остается на совести того, кто использует код. Хотя, интересные варианты по этой проблеме я бы тоже глянул, это же фиг ограничишь.

UPD2: пока не смог придумать, можно ли оборачивать один такой блок в другой, а то сейчас в итоге на аборте внутреннего блока внешний снова уходит на обработку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не кажется, что существует общее решение проблемы. Поскольку то, что вы кодируете — это по сути бизнес-логика, которая «разнообразна как сама жизнь», вы не сможете заранее покрыть все возможные случаи.

Навскидку что с кодом не так:

1. Выполнение происходит синхронно, блокирующим образом. Это не всегда так, очень часто «строительные блоки» бизнес-логики формируются из асинхронных процедур. Этой возможности у вас нет.
2. Модель подписки на событие у стороннего объекта мне кажется слишком сложной и нарушающей линейную логику. У вас один, статический экземпляр `ExceptionHandler`'а, а значит, вам придётся подписывать несколько обработчиков одновременно. При этом нужен механизм, который решает, ответственен ли данный обработчик за данную ошибку или нет. Этой логики у вас нет, и она получится достаточно сложной. Также у универсального объекта должны возникать проблемы с многопоточным доступом, как только вы попытаетесь сделать его сложнее.
3. Очень часто простого повторения действия недостаточно, т. к. условия не поменялись, и значит, новое действие завершится с той же ошибкой. Нужно какое-нибудь дополнительное действие: сделать паузу, подобрать другие исходные данные, провести диалог с пользователем и. т. д. В вашем дизайне эти все дополнительные действия придётся паковать в обработчик события, что не очень читаемо.

Мне кажется, вы не должны пытаться построить универсальную логику, это и не выйдет, т. к. случаев очень много. Намного лучше, проще и эффективнее писать маленькие вспомогательные функции на каждый случай жизни, и собирать их в классы-утилиты.

Например, такую простую логику

```
static async Task<T> TrySeveralTimesWithGrowingTimeout<T>(
    int count, Func<Task<T>> taskCreator, TimeSpan timeoutDiff, Action<string> failureLogger)
{
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // count раз:
    {
        timeout += timeoutDiff; // нарастим таймаут
        try
        {                               // пытаемся выполнить Task, если не будет
            return await taskCreator(); // исключения, возвращаем результат
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (i < count - 1) // ловим исключение всегда, кроме
        {                                         // последней итерации
            failureLogger($"Operation failed #{i}, retrying after {timeout}. " +
                          $"Exception was {ex.Message}"); // залогировали
        }
        await Task.Delay(timeout);     // выдерживаем паузу до следующего запуска
    }
    // сюда мы не попадём, т. к. если последняя итерация провалилась,
    // то было выброшено исключение
    throw new Exception("cannot happen");
}
```

достаточно сложно закодировать в терминах `ExceptionHandler`'а.

Тестовой функцией пользоваться так:

```
async Task<string> GetFileContent(string path)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}

// ...

try
{
    var text = await TrySeveralTimesWithGrowingTimeout(
            count: 3,
            taskCreator: () => GetFileContent(path),
            timeoutDiff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            failureLogger: Console.Error.WriteLine);
    // тут ещё километр логики
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine($"Failed: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Но это не универсальная функция, это просто пример того, что можно легко закодировать вручную.

Comment: c#6 во все поля :-D

Comment: @Grundy: А то! Нужно пропагандировать прогресс!

Comment: Я честно так и не осилил обработку исключений с await, такое ощущение, что её просто хрен сделаешь.

Comment: @Monk: Почему, странно. Там же всё очень просто. `await` бросает исключение, возникшее в `Task`'е.

Comment: Брр, прочитал ваш пример кода, так и не понял зачем он =) Как этим пользоваться, можете добавить пример?

Comment: @Monk: Добавил пример. Попробуйте, например, запустить программу, и после этого создать файл, из которого будет прочитан текст.

Comment: Использование понял. Я посмотрю и подумаю - повторение асинхронных операций ессна полезно, но я не подумал о том варианте, что вы предложили.

Comment: Отдохнул от кода, перечитал всё. 2 и 3 пункты я так понимаю ничем хорошим не закрываются, кроме ручной обработки каждого конкретного случая? По крайней мере, я не видел нигде такого кода.

Comment: @Monk: Ну, это именно то, к чему я веду. Общего решения я не вижу, лучше кодировать хелпер-функции каждый раз.

Answer (score 3):

"Я не доктор, но посмотреть могу" (С)

Готовое решение найдено на просторах Сети и выглядит весьма неплохо:

```
public interface ISequentialActivity
{
    bool Run();
}

public enum UserAction
{
    Abort,
    Retry, 
    Ignore
}

public class FailureEventArgs
{
    public UserAction Action = UserAction.Abort;
}

public class SequentialActivityMachine
{
    private Queue<ISequentialActivity> activities = new Queue<ISequentialActivity>();
    public event Action<FailureEventArgs> OnFailed;    
    protected void PerformOnFailed(FailureEventArgs e)
    {
        var failed = this.OnFailed;
        if (failed != null)
            failed(e);
    }
    public void Add(ISequentialActivity activity) { this.activities.Enqueue(activity); }
    public void Run()
    {
        while (this.activities.Count > 0)
        {
            var next = activities.Peek();
            if (!next.Run())
            {
                var failureEventArgs = new FailureEventArgs();
                PerformOnFailed(failureEventArgs);

                if (failureEventArgs.Action == UserAction.Abort)
                    return;
                if (failureEventArgs.Action == UserAction.Retry)
                    continue;
            }

            activities.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Принципиальной разницы не вижу. Относительно моего варианта -- добавлена зависимость от интерфейса, добавлена необходимость вызывать `Run` у `SequentialActivityMachine`.

Answer (score 2):

Есть способ с использованием [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).
Решение разрабатывалось на основе примеров: [пример №1](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception#intercepting-method), [пример №2](http://samples.postsharp.net/#PostSharp.Samples.AutoRetry/AutoRetryAttribute.cs).

Преимущества:

- Исходный код подвергается минимальным изменениям, добавляется лишь один атрибут к методам.
- Никаких ограничений на методы. Атрибут может быть применен как к статическим, так и к инстансным методам, к конструкторам и свойствам, с параметрами или без.

Недостатки:

- Хотя PostSharp имеет бесплатную версию, нормальная версия стоит денег. *Быть может есть бесплатные аналоги, имеющие схожую функциональность...*
- Автообработка исключений работает только для метода целиком, и не работает для части метода.
- Пусть и небольшое, но увеличение времени компиляции и времени выполнения кода.
- Дополнительная зависимость в проекте.
- Не предусмотрена возможность запихнуть штатными средствами делегат в атрибут, поэтому текущий обработчик исключений лежит в статическом свойстве `CurrentExceptionHandler.HandlerFunc`. Это костыль.

Код:

```
public enum ExceptionHandlerResult
{
    Abort,
    Retry,
    Ignore
}

public static class CurrentExceptionHandler
{
    public static Func<Exception, ExceptionHandlerResult> HandlerFunc { get; set; } = DefaultHandlerFunc;

    public static ExceptionHandlerResult DefaultHandlerFunc(Exception e)
    {
        var response = MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        switch (response)
        {
            case DialogResult.Abort:
                return ExceptionHandlerResult.Abort;
            case DialogResult.Retry:
                return ExceptionHandlerResult.Retry;
            case DialogResult.Ignore:
                return ExceptionHandlerResult.Ignore;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}

[PSerializable]
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If the value is negative, ignore the retries count.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxRetries { get; set; }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        int retriesCount = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnInvoke(args);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception during attempt {0} of calling method {1}.{2}: {3}",
                    retriesCount, args.Method.DeclaringType, args.Method.Name, e.Message);

                var handlerFunc = CurrentExceptionHandler.HandlerFunc;
                if (handlerFunc == null)
                    throw;

                var response = handlerFunc(e);

                switch (response)
                {
                    case ExceptionHandlerResult.Abort:
                        throw;
                    case ExceptionHandlerResult.Retry:
                        retriesCount++;
                        if (MaxRetries >= 0 && retriesCount > MaxRetries)
                            throw;
                        continue;
                    case ExceptionHandlerResult.Ignore:
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
[HandleException(MaxRetries = 10)]
private static void TestMethod(int n)
{
    throw new ApplicationException();
}

TestMethod(1);
```

Чтобы использовать свой обработчик исключений, необходимо установить его в качестве значения статического свойства `CurrentExceptionHandler.HandlerFunc`.

Comment: С постшарпом ни разу не работал, попробую ваш пример и посмотрю, как получится. Идея сама интересная, а вот с обработчиком уже грустновато становится. Надо смотреть.

Comment: Попробовал. В целом - выглядит интересно. Идею с максимальным количеством попыток точно утащу себе в любом виде, не подумал даже. Работать - работает, но ограничение того, что использовать можно только метод, плюс ограничения бесплатной версии... не для домашнего использования всё таки.